# AngularJS intellisense in VSCode stopped working - any idea why?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

weird thing - it was working before and suddenly stopped working.

Of course I installed typings for angular in my project (and some other languages):

> typings dt~angular --global --save

So I have typings.json file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160802155123",
    "angular-route": "registry:dt/angular-route#1.3.0+20160317120654",
    "angular-sanitize": "registry:dt/angular-sanitize#1.3.0+20160317120654",
    "bootstrap": "registry:dt/bootstrap#3.3.5+20160619023404",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160704162008"
  }
}
```

Sure I have the typings folder with all the *.d.ts files in it.

Any idea why I dont get Angular intellisense anymore?

**UPDATE** It seems typings dont work in .cshtml files.
I had .cshtml file, after renamed it to .html, the intelisense began to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems typings dont work in .cshtml files.

I had .cshtml file, after renamed it to .html, the intelisense began to work.

Renamed back to .cshtml - stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript intellisense in VS Code doesn't seem to work without `tsconfig.json` file anymore since the last update. Add one to your project with this contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```